# Obtain ID or description of bypassed alert

Tags: excel, vba, alert

I'm developing my macro for being able to run fully automated without any issues for a longer time period. But from time to time I get alerts during runtime (for example *Excel cannot display more than 1000 labels*). I want to be notified about any ongoing issues such as alerts without stopping the macro.

The well known `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` is not enough for me since I would like to identify any kind of alerts and at least put its ID or description into my log file whenever it is due.

Is there any way to get the ID or any kind of description of the bypassed alert?